# Given any two points in an attractor, is one of them always (almost) reachable from the other?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider a continuous dynamical system with bounded orbits, described by some system of ODE's. Let the flow of the system be $\phi$; i.e. $x(t + T) = \phi(T, x(t))$ for all states $x$ and times $t, T$.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an attractor of the system and let $x \in \mathcal{A}$ be a state within the attractor. Define the state's orbit as $\mathcal{O}(x) = \lbrace \phi(t, x) \; \mid \; t \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$. Is $\mathcal{A} = \overline{\mathcal{O}(x)}$ for all $x \in \mathcal{A}$? [Note: $\overline{\mathcal{O}(x)}$ denotes the closure of $\mathcal{O}(x)$.]

Note: The proposition is trivially true for periodic orbits and equilibrium points, but does it hold in general? If not, a simple counter-example would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

*Edit note*: The old title of the question was "Are all points within an attractor reachable from some other point within it?". That title did not semantically match with the question posed in the content of the post -- it had a trivial positive answer. Therefore, the title was changed in subsequent edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider three equilibria connected by three heteroclinic orbits (polycycle).